# Hash table that includes SQL Server name, SQL port, and SQL instance

Tags: powershell

I'm running a lot of `invoke-sqlcmd` commands, all with a different server name, different port, and a different instance.

From what I've read a hash table is the way to go

1. Can a hash table be a separate file?
2. How do I create a table that includes server name, port number, and instance?
3. How do I incorporate that into the script?

Comment: i would use an array/arraylist/generic.list as appropriate ... and put custom objects into that. then you can simply iterate thru the collection.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: if you have a CSV file with the info in it, you can use `Import-CSV` and get a collection of objects. the header will be the property names, and the other rows will be the objects with each column a property of that object. that lets you use `$Item.ComputerName` to get the computer name, `$Item.Port` to get hte port info, etc. ///// plus, you can easily create/save/load/edit those items. ///// take a look at `Get-Help Import-Csv -Examples` for some nifty examples. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

A PS Custom object is well-suited for containing your data. Consider

```
$o = [PSCustomObject]@{
  'Name' = 'dev'
  'Server' = 'Server1'
  'Instance' = '\dev'
  'Port' = '50000'
}
```

Now the `$o` object contains `NoteProperty` members that contain data. Accessing is simple enough:

```
$o.server+$o.instance+','+$o.port
Server1\dev,50000
```

Hashtables in Powershell are created with built-in syntax: `$myHashTable = @{}`.

A quick demo how to work with hash tables is in order. Let's populate a list of aforementioned custom objects first. Like so,

```
# Empty array
$l = @()
# Add some servers
$l += [PSCustomObject]@{
  'Name' = 'dev'
  'Server' = 'Server1'
  'Instance' = '\dev'
  'Port' = '50000'
}
$l += [PSCustomObject]@{
  'Name' = 'test'
  'Server' = 'Server1'
  'Instance' = '\test'
  'Port' = '50001'
}
$l += [PSCustomObject]@{
  'Name' = 'qa'
  'Server' = 'Server1'
  'Instance' = '\qa'
  'Port' = '50002'
}
$l += [PSCustomObject]@{
  'Name' = 'prod'
  'Server' = 'Server2'
  'Instance' = '\prod'
  'Port' = '50000'
}
```

Now there's a list of server objects, but it's hard to access a specific one. Server's index in the list must be known, or the list otherwise searched.

Consider a hash table: its contents can be retrieved based on a key. Let's use `Name` property as the key and add the servers into a hash table:

```
# Empty hashtable
$ht = @{}
# Iterate server list and add each PSObject into the hasthtable
$l | % { $ht.add($_.name, $_  )}
# Print results
$ht
Name Value
---- -----
qa   @{Name=qa; Server=Server1; Instance=\qa; Port=50002}
dev  @{Name=dev; Server=Server1; Instance=\dev; Port=50000}
prod @{Name=prod; Server=Server2; Instance=\prod; Port=50000}
test @{Name=test; Server=Server1; Instance=\test; Port=50001}

#Access the prod server object
$ht.prod

Name Server  Instance Port
---- ------  -------- ----
prod Server2 \prod    50000

# Get production's port
$ht.prod.port
50000

# Generate a connection string to prod
"Server={0},{1}" -f $($ht.prod.server+$ht.prod.instance), $ht.prod.port
Server=Server2\prod,50000
```

As for how to use file-based hashtable, look up [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-6) and `Import-Clixml`.